# From Database to datatable to generic collection to JSon via JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, service, web

Good people, I am in a dilemma and time is definitely not on my side.

**My objective**
I want to get records from the database via a dataset/datatable, then to a generic collection and finally to a JSon object using JQuery in the client side to improve user experience.

**What works so far**
My code works in the web service  up to the point when the data is handed over to the client/browser.

**What I am not sure about**
With my little or virtually no experience with neither JSon nor JQuery, the data from the web service is not displaying in the web browser. I don't know where the problem is.

**The code**
Here I enclose the rest of my code:

1. The hotelrates.vb file, the code behind of the hotelrates.asmx file

> ```
> Imports System.Web
> Imports System.Web.Services
> Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
> Imports System.Web.Script.Services
> Imports System.Collections.Generic
> Imports System.Linq
> Imports System.Data
> Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
> Imports System.Reflection
>
> <WebService([Namespace]:="http://tourslogin.net/")> _
> <WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
> <ScriptService()> _
> Public Class Hotelrates
>  Inherits WebService
>  <WebMethod()> _
>  Public Function GetRates() As Generic.List(Of Rate)
>     Dim m_globalfunctions As New clsGlobalFunctions
>     Dim SQL As String = "SELECT
> ```
>
> tblhotelrates.ID,Supplier,From_date,To_Date,Room_type,Room_basis FROM
>   tblhotelrates,tblHotels WHERE tblhotelrates.SupplierID=tblHotels.ID "
>
> ```
>      Dim clsDB As New clsDatabase("jksafarisdbConnectionString")
>      Dim dsCostingDetails As DataSet
>      Try
>         dsCostingDetails = clsDB.QueryDataSet(SQL, "jksafarisdbConnectionString")
>
>         Dim s As Rate
>         Dim c As New Generic.List(Of Rate)
>         For Each dr As DataRow In dsCostingDetails.Tables(0).Rows
>             s = New Rate
>             With s
>                 .myID = m_globalfunctions.CheckDBNull(dr("ID"))
>                 .Supplier = m_globalfunctions.CheckDBNull(dr("Supplier"))
>             End With
>             c.Add(s)
>         Next
>
>         Return c
>     Catch ex As Exception
>         MsgBox(ex.Message)
>     Finally
>         clsDB.Close()
>     End Try
>
> End Function End Class <Serializable()> _ Public Class Rate
> Private _myID As String
> Private _supplier As String
>
> Public Property myID() As String
>     Get
>         Return _myID
>     End Get
>     Set(ByVal value As String)
>         _myID = value
>     End Set
> End Property
>
> Public Property Supplier() As String
>     Get
>         Return _supplier
>     End Get
>     Set(ByVal value As String)
>         _supplier = value
>     End Set
> End Property End Class
> ```

1. The client side of the code JQuery/Json

> ```
> <div id="output"></div>
> <script type="text/javascript">
> $(function () {
>
>  $('#Button1').click(getRates);
>
>  });
>
>
>
> function getRates() {
>
> $.ajax({
>
>     type: "POST",
>
>     url: "Hotelrates.asmx/GetRates",
>
>     data: "{}",
>
>     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>
>     dataType: "json",
>
>     success: function (response) {
>
>         var rates = response.d;
>
>         $('#output').empty();
>
>         $.each(rates, function () {
>
>             $('#output').append('<p><strong>' + Rate.myID + ' ' +
>
>                         Rate.myID + '</strong><br /> Year: ' +
>
>                         Rate.mySupplier + '<br />');
>
>         });
>
>     },
>
>     failure: function (msg) {
>
>         $('#output').text(msg);
>
>     }
> });
>      }
>
>   </script>
>   </asp:Content>
> ```

Comment: Have you debugged the js and checked where it falls?

Answer (score 2):

The Rate variable in your js seems to be not declared.

Try to change your success callback function with this:

```
success: function (response) {
    var rates = response.d;
    $('#output').empty();

    for (var r in rates) {
        $('#output').append('<p><strong>' + rates[r].myID + ' ' +
                    rates[r].myID + '</strong><br /> Year: ' +
                    rates[r].mySupplier + '<br />');

    }
}
```

Comment: that's a good start but I think there are other problems in the OP's code.  For example, why is he using `response.d`?  Nothing seems to indicate that the `d` variable is being set.  @Lindelani, one trick you can use is to use the script debuggers in Chrome or Firefox and put a breakpoint inside your success handler.  There you can inspect the object that came back from the server and easily see how to iterate over it.

Comment: response.d is used because is the default wrapper used by the standard .asmx web service, I don't see a problem there.

Comment: Thank you guys for the advice,I am greatful. The function provided by tanathos works well. Thank you.